# "mpi.h" file not found Xcode 8

Tags: c, xcode, mpi

I need to work with MPI in C in Xcode 8.3, but when I do the `#include <mpi.h>` a issue comes up: "mpi.h file not found". I already have OpenMpi, but it's a compiler error. How can I fix it?

When I compile it from Terminal with mpicc, it doesn't seem to have any problem, but in Xcode I can't Build the project.

I just expect/want the Xcode project to build, but it doesn't recognize the `<mpi.h>` header.

Do I have to install anything else or is it just about Xcode settings?

Comment: No idea how your Xcode project is setup, but usually to fix problem like that you have to modify: Select your project, "Build Settings->"Header Search Path"

Comment: When building MPI programs you typically direct your IDE (XCode) here to use the MPI wrappers (e.g. `mpicc`) instead of the usual compilers (e.g. `gcc`). Manually setting include and library paths, and MPI libs is both ugly and inefficient IMHO.

Comment: I've alredy tried to copy the "mpi.h" file into /usr/include, and also making an alias, but "Operation not permitted" (Terminal message).

Comment: once again, the easiest way to resolve this is to use the MPI wrappers instead of starting hacking your system.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking for a permanent solution, not just for this project. I'd like to build MPI programs, whenever I want, without using wrappers each time, just once. I just wonder if it's possible

Comment: if you are not using the MPI wrappers, then you have to set the include and library paths, and link with the right library (and that depends on your MPI vendor). I cannot see how that would make it a permanent solution.